# Double entry book keeping for hardcore personal finance

Tags: cloud-service, finance

I'm looking for some experienced feedback with double entry book keeping software that can be tuned for personal finances. I'm not sure if I'm a rare breed, but I like to know my worth at all times and my extensive research (and trials) have revealed that the double entry system is by far the best for keeping track of every financial detail.

However, I'm also aware that the primary use of this system is in small businesses and therefore most software built on the system is geared towards that end.

With that being said, does anyone have an experienced (as in used it extensively) suggestion for double entry book keeping software?

The one I'm looking at the most right now is Gnucash, but there are few qualms I have with it:

- Out of date GUI. Not user friendly.
- Does not readily support simultaneous editing (For when I want to
  work with my wife).
- Bloated, takes way too long for tasks on what I would consider
  exceptional hardware.  Not aimed at personal finance.

What I'm looking for:

- Fresh GUI designed around showing what you really need with the
  option of digging further.
- Preferably runs in the cloud in order to facilitate universal access
  and simultaneous editing.
- Geared towards personal finance and not small business finance  Still
  being maintained and not abandoned.
- An integrated feature for budgeting (with reports)

Comment: Not sure if it's cloud, but double entry similar to gnucash but updated would be [kmymomey](http://kmymoney2.sourceforge.net/index-home.html)